# unable to run the hide function in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

hi i am new to jquery i am trying to tweak this fiddle a little
http://jsfiddle.net/handtrix/dzr521qs/
 and unable to do so  . what i want to do is on clicking the submit button this popup hides . here is my piece of code to hide it but it's not working and i am unable to figure out the mistake

```
 $("#hide-me").click(function(){
    $(".content").hide("slow", function(){
        console.log("scfzd");
        alert("The paragraph is now hidden");
    });
 });
```

I have assigned id "#hide-me" to the submit button.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is that `content`?  It should be `.content`

Comment: u are right my mistake . but still not working

Comment: Is there any javascript file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dzr521qs/162/)**

First you have to add class `hide-me` and not `id` because you have more than one `submit` button and you souldn't duplicate ids in same document :

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-block hide-me">Submit</button>
```

Second use `.popover('hide')` to hide `popover` content :

```
$(document).on("click", ".hide-me", function() {
    $('.popover-markup>.trigger').popover('hide');
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: one more thing how can i make it work if i swap the hide class with some other name or add some other class in front of it ...this is working fine just trying to learn a little bit more

Comment: No problem, if you change the `hide-me` class just change it in the both (input and js function) and it will work, you're free to add other classes, it will not create a problem.

Comment: well i thought that too and tried but it doesn't seem to work and return an error in console 
"Uncaught TypeError: i[n] is not a function" some error in bootstrap library.

Comment: i am talking abut "hide" in class="content hide" not hide-me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87704/discussion-between-zakaria-acharki-and-affan).

Answer (score 0):

Keep you code inside jquery ready event,

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
       $("#hide-me").click(function(){
           $(".content").hide("slow", function(){
               console.log("scfzd");
               alert("The paragraph is now hidden");
           });
       });   
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).on("mousedown", ".hide-me", function() {
    $('.popover-markup>.trigger').popover('hide');
});
```

Its also Working ..